# Button style differs on different screens and devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create close button using Bootstrap. The problem is that the button style differs on different sizes. For example, if I shrink the browser into small phone size or on real device, the style looks like this(which is wrong):

[image]

But it should look like this(which it does only when using the chrome developer tools screen size tool.:

[image]

This is the button:

```
<button type="button" class="close hide-filters btn" aria-label="Close">
    <span class="close-icon" ><i class="fa fa-times" style="color: #999; font-size: 16px;"></i></span>
</button>
```

What could cause this problem? Why the user agent stylesheet overrides it? And only if shrinking manually and on real device the button style is even more different.

Comment: Seems same for me, can you inspect and check any other styles applied or not? http://jsfiddle.net/q4j9tsgw/

Comment: try to add `aria-hidden="true"` in `<span>` after `class="close-icon"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was working is this(removed the `button`):

```
<span class="close-icon close hide-filters btn"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color: #999; font-size: 16px;"></i></span>
```